# Cant build a CNN with keras for vectors - problem with dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Let us say that I build an extreamly simple CNN with Keras to classify vectors.

My input (X_train) is a matrix in which each row is a vector and each column is a feature. My input labels (y_train) is matrix where each line is a one hot encoded vector. This is a binary classifier.

my CNN is built as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64,3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', matrics = 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size = 32)
```

But when I try to run this code, I get back this error message:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_23: expected ndim=3, found 
ndim=2
```

why would keras expect 3 dims? one dim for samples, and one for features. And more importantly, how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the shape of x_train and y_train?

Answer (score 0):

X_train is suppose to have the shape: (batch_size, steps, input_dim), [see documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D#input_shape). It seems like you are missing one of the dimensions.
I would guess input_dim in your case is 1 and that is why it is missing. If so, change the

`model.fit`

line to

`model.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_train,-1), y_train,batch_size = 32)`

Your code is not a minimal working example, so I am not able to verify if that is the only problem, but this should hopefully fix your current error message.

Answer (score 0):

A `Conv1D` layer expects an input with shape `(samples, width, channels)`, so this does not match your input data, producing an error.

The convolution operation is done on the `width` dimension, so assuming that you want to do convolution on what you call features, then you should reshape your data to add a dummy `channels` dimension with a value of one:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
```